# App Doesn't Appear Under "Notifications" In Settings

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, notifications, push

I've been working on an app which uses push notifications and after a few namechanges etc, the app is now not showing up in the "Notifications" section of the iPhone's settings app.

Now I assume it will be ok for a new user installing it but I need to test it on my own phone first.  This problems also means that my app receives the `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *) error` method every time.

Any idea how to reset everything so the app will ask me for permission again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention that the app has been renamed.  Make sure your app's identifier still matches the App ID on the portal.  If it's changed you may need to create a new App ID and recreate your SSL certificates and provisioning profile.